# aurelia custom plugin that uses a custom attribute - cant find custom attribute

Tags: node.js, webpack, aurelia

Hi i have downloaded the hello world aurelia skelton plugin  from https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-plugin . 
i then reference this from the package.json file in a fresh copy of the aurelia esnext/webpack skelton (https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack) as my main app. 
i can then use the plugin in one of my components with

```
<require from="aurelia-skeleton-plugin/hello-world"></require>
```

at the top of the view and placing `<hello-world></hello-world>` anywhere on the view. this works great.

next step i want to try is adding a custom attribute to my plugin. in the src folder of my plugin i added the simple custom attribute

```
export class RedSquareCustomAttribute {
  static inject = [Element];

  constructor(element){
    this.element = element;
    this.element.style.width = this.element.style.height = '100px';
    this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

i then reference this in my hello-world.html page with the following code

```
<require from="./red-square"></require>
  <div red-square></div>
```

run gulp build,  then reinstall the package in my main app. in the main app npm start builds ok but the browser gives me the error:
Cannot find module './aurelia-skeleton-plugin/red-square'

ive read lots of docs but nothing gives an example of this scenario and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your module actually called `red-square.js`?

Comment: yes im just using the simple example from the docs http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-custom-attributes/2 just to get it working first

Comment: I updated my answer below, please give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things to try- though I got it to work out of the box from the tutorial in the link that you provided.

Confirm that babelOptions in `config.js` has `classProperties`.

```
  babelOptions: {
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system",
      "es7.classProperties"
    ]
  },
```

Next, please double check that your files are properly placed in the `src` folder and named:

- `red-sqaure.js`
- `simple-attribute-usage.html`

Then, whichever HTML file has your content- your shell / app, do something like the following:

`<compose view="simple-attribute-usage.html" viewmodel="red-square"></compose>`

though I was able to get original HTML to work

```
<require from="./red-square"></require>
  <div red-square></div>
```

Comment: i tried adding the babelOptions in config.js in the skeleton-plugin project but still no luck. there doesnt seem to be a config.js file in the skelton-esnext-wepback project.

Comment: got it working. the problem turned out to be that i had downloaded both skeleton packages as zip files. once i ran them as git clones it worked. there must have been some corruption that took place in the compression/decompression of the zip files. the fact that you got it working out the box pointed me in right direction cheers